# How to open a full browser when clicking on an ad

Tags: browser, ads, mobile-application

I am not sure the correct terminology for this, but basically often times when I am on my phone and click on an in-app advertisement, a "temporary browser" is opened up. See this image:

[image]

I am creating an advertising campaign (very new to this), and I want it so that when a user clicks on my ad, it is opened in a "real browser". Like this:

[image]

The reason is because with the "temporary browser", the website is lost if the user, for instance, presses the back button. I want it so that that will not happen, and having the page open on the "real browser" makes it a bit simpler. If the user closes the app they clicked the ad in, the temporary browser would be lost, but if they close their google chrome for instance (or their phone battery dies), then the same page they were on before chrome was closed will be reopened when they open chrome again.
Is it possible to make this distinction between which browser would be opened? If it helps at all, I am making this ad to be shown in Tinder where it can be clicked on.